# SourceTree/Fork not showing conflicts

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, bitbucket, fork, atlassian-sourcetree

I am having issues with SourceTree and Fork showing conflicts.  I am using Unity and am updating specific parts of a prefab that is also being used by another colleague albeit different parts than what I'm using.  The bigger problem here is that when I merge into a fresh branch off of her branch it doesn't tell me there are any conflicts and then overrides her work with mine.  Does anyone know why it isn't showing conflicts in the first place?

I have tried deleting and making a brand new clone of git.  Tried merging and pulling into the new branch from my original branch.  All with the same result.  Even used the terminal git remote prune origin.

Thank you.

Comment: If you start with what she has, and change things, and then merge, why would you expect your changes to conflict with her lack-of-changes?

Comment: Well, she had changes that's why it was so weird.  We ended up just making note of what we did and just added it in the same branch and avoided the merge entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up just making note of what we did and just added it in the same branch and avoided the merge entirely.